# Add Cometd to an existing Maven project

Tags: maven, cometd

I am trying to use the Cometd framework in an existing Maven project. I am new to this and don't understand how to handle this. If I start a new project using Cometd and Maven everything is fine, but how can I add the framework to an existing project?

This is the dependency section of the working cometd project:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cometd.javascript</groupId>
        <artifactId>cometd-javascript-dojo</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cometd.javascript</groupId>
        <artifactId>cometd-javascript-jquery</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cometd.javascript</groupId>
        <artifactId>cometd-examples-dojo</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cometd.javascript</groupId>
        <artifactId>cometd-examples-jquery</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>cometd-java-examples</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>cometd-java-oort</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>cometd-java-server</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>cometd-java-websocket-javax-server</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax-websocket-server-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When adding these to the existing project, that needs to use cometD and trying to build it using Maven, I get the following error: `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.4:war (default-war) on project autodeploy.web.ui.war: overlay [ id org.cometd.javascript:cometd-javascript-jquery] is not a dependency of the project.`

Comment: It is unclear what is your problem. Have you tried adding the CometD dependencies you have in your CometD-only project that works fine to the existing project ?

Comment: I edited the dependency section into the question. I tried just adding those in the dependencies of the existing projects pom.xml. That didn't do the trick. Does that clearify where I am at?

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem ?

Comment: I tried to put this problem on hold, but now I need to get through this. I added the dependencies of the cometD project to the new project, but when I try to build it using Maven, I get the following Error: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.4:war (default-war) on project [xxxxxxx]: overlay [ id org.cometd.javascript:cometd-javascript-jquery] is not a dependency of the project.